# scanUpToCharactersFromSet stops after one loop

Tags: objective-c, csv, cocoa, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to get the contents of a CSV file into an array. When I've done this before I had one record per line, and used the newline character with `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`, passing `newlineCharacterSet` as the character set:

```
while ([lineScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] 
                                   intoString:&line])
```

Now, I'm working with a file where many of the entries themselves contain newline characters. I've tried adding a unique character to the end of each record (a `*` character) but my loop only runs once. Is there something which is making the while loop break that I don't know about? Here's the code I'm using now:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[self delegate] filePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSScanner *lineScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:data];
NSString *line = nil;

// Start parsing the CSV file
while ([lineScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"]
                    intoString:&line]) {
    NSArray *elements = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog("Name: %@", [elements objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

**Edit: ** Thanks to Peter's answer below, I found that my scanner was stuck behind the * character. I added this line in the loop:

```
[lineScanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"] intoString:NULL];
```

and now it's working like it should.

Comment: You don't need the * separator. You can scan for plain line breaks just fine (now that your loop is fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through one pass at a time:

1. First:

   ```
   while ([lineScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] intoString:&line]) {
   ```

   The scanner puts everything before the line break into `line`. It advances up to the newline.
2. Second:

   ```
   while ([lineScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] intoString:&line]) {
   ```

   The scanner is already on a line break, so it scans no characters. [As documented](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:), since it scanned no characters, it returns `NO`. Your loop terminates.

The solution is to [scan the line break](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:) at the end of the loop, to get the scanner past it. You can pass `NULL` for the output parameter, assuming you don't care what the line break was.

This is correct behavior: If you did/do care what the characters you scanned up to were, this lets you obtain them. That would be more difficult if NSScanner scanned past the characters automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter. The loop that used `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` was working OK with a CSV file with one record per line. With the multi-line record CSV, I put a * at the end of each record and tried `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"]` but it failed. Presumably stuck at the * character. I thought about your answer and added the code above. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the while condition is wrong. According to the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147), it should be something like:

```
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    [lineScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"] intoString:&line]
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As long as there's anything yet to be scanned, `isAtEnd` will not return `YES`. Thus, that's an infinite loop, since it never scans past the end of the first line. See my answer.